# Race Condition in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception, race-condition

I am the only developer at a small business, and I have inherited some legacy code in an asp.net mvc application that basically "reroutes" an entity from one business department to another. The main entity has a collection of "step" objects, and to achieve the desired "reroute" functionality, the action adds a couple steps to this collection and sets the properties of other steps. This is the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Re_Route_TIR(int tir_id, double this_step, int group_id, string routing_reason, int re_route_group_id, int selected_opportunity_code, string opportunity_code_comment)
    {
        TIR_OV_Helper helper = new TIR_OV_Helper();

        tir_departments department = db.tir_departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.department_id == group_id);
        tir_tir_steps currentStep = db.tir_tir_steps.Where(x => x.tir_id == tir_id).OrderBy(x => x.tir_step).FirstOrDefault(x => x.tir_step_date == null);

        try
        {
            var user_id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();


            tir_tirs tir = db.tir_tirs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.tir_id == tir_id);
            var original_step = tir.steps.OrderBy(x => x.tir_step).FirstOrDefault(o => o.tir_step_date == null);

            original_step.tir_step_date = DateTime.Now;
            original_step.assignedUserId = user_id;
            original_step.tir_step_state_id = 4;

            List<tir_tir_steps> steps = db.tir_tir_steps.Where(x => x.tir_id == tir_id).ToList();
            foreach (tir_tir_steps step in steps)
            {
                if (step.tir_step > original_step.tir_step)
                {
                    step.tir_step += 20;
                }
            }

            tir_tir_steps newstep = new tir_tir_steps();
            tir_tir_steps routedstep = new tir_tir_steps();

            newstep.tir_step = original_step.tir_step + 10;
            newstep.tir_department_id = re_route_group_id;
            newstep.tir_operation_id = 33;
            newstep.tir_step_state_id = 8;
            newstep.tir_id = tir_id;
            newstep.tir_department = db.tir_departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.department_id == re_route_group_id);

            tir.steps.Add(newstep);

            routedstep.tir_step = newstep.tir_step + 10;
            routedstep.tir_id = tir_id;
            routedstep.tir_department_id = original_step.tir_department_id;
            routedstep.tir_operation_id = original_step.tir_operation_id;
            routedstep.tir_department = db.tir_departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.department_id == original_step.tir_department_id);

            tir.steps.Add(routedstep);

            helper.SetNextStep(8, tir_id);   // if no resource then 8 = "waiting"


            var previously_with_dept_id = re_route_group_id;
            var currently_with_dept_id = helper.GetCurrentStepGroupId(tir_id); //GetCurrentStepDepartmentId(tir_id);
            tir.current_operation_id = 33; // db.tir_operations.Find(operation_id);
            tir.current_dept_group_id = re_route_group_id;
            tir.currently_with = "Open";

            ////

            tir_tir_opportunity opportunity_code_data = new tir_tir_opportunity
            {
                tir_id = tir_id,
                tir_oppt_id = selected_opportunity_code,
                opptUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                oppt_report_date = DateTime.Now,
                oppt_report_group_id = department.department_id,
                opp_code_reason = opportunity_code_comment,
                operation = "Re-Route"
            };

            tir_comments dcomment = new tir_comments();
            dcomment.comment_date = DateTime.Now;
            dcomment.comment_user_name = User.Identity.GetFullName();
            dcomment.comment_text = opportunity_code_comment;
            dcomment.department_id = group_id;
            dcomment.department_name = db.tir_departments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.department_id == group_id).department_name;
            dcomment.tir_id = tir_id;

            tir.department_comments.Add(dcomment);
            db.tir_tir_opportunity.Add(opportunity_code_data);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { id = tir_id });
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

I know that it is a very ugly and long action and needs to be refactored, but it works without fail when I run it on my machine. However, some users that have been testing this code have been experiencing null reference exceptions. This is the error message:

```
Error Message - at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.AddRelationshipDetectedByForeignKey(Dictionary`2 relationships, Dictionary`2 principalRelationships, EntityKey relatedKey, EntityEntry relatedEntry, RelatedEnd relatedEndFrom) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInForeignKeys() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInForeignKeys(IList`1 entries) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate) at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync() at TIR_Sandbox_New.Controllers.LevelCompleteController.<Re_Route_TIR>d__6.MoveNext()
```

I am assuming that this is some sort of race condition within Entity Framework, but I am fairly new to Entity Framework. I figure that some thread within Entity Framework is isn't completing quickly enough for these testers, and that is why it is breaking for them. How can I fix the problem and make it work for all users? Also, how can I avoid similar problems in the future? Any help would be appreciated!

I am guessing that the relationship between the tirs and steps might also be relevant, so I am posting those as well.

```
public class tir_tirs
{
    public tir_tirs()
    {
        this.steps = new HashSet<tir_tir_steps>();
        ...
    }
    public virtual ICollection<tir_tir_steps> steps { get; set; }
}




public class tir_tir_steps
{
    [Key]
    public int tir_steps_id { get; set; }
    public int tir_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("tir_id")]
    public virtual tir_tirs tir { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> tir_step { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> tir_step_date { get; set; }
    public int? tir_step_state_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("tir_step_state_id")]
    public virtual tir_steps_status tir_step_state { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Try removing the async from the method and don't await on the save changes and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem ended up being the relationship between the "original_step" and the assignedUserd. I that because of the way entity framework works, when the "assignedUserId" was set the way it was, it was having trouble finding the other end of the relationship quickly enough under certain conditions. I deleted this relationship as it wasn't necessary, and the method is now working fine. Any additional insight would be welcome! Hopefully this helps someone else down the road.

Comment: @ryant You should post your comment as an answer if you don't mind.